# Undefined methods in Neo4j / ActiveGraph setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am attempting to follow the instructions from documentation here: http://neo4jrb.io/#getting-started

I added these gems and ran `bundle install`

```
gem 'activegraph'
gem 'neo4j-ruby-driver'
```

and in my `config/application.rb` I have:

```
config.neo4j.driver.url = ENV['NEO4J_URL'] || 'neo4j://localhost:7687'
    config.neo4j.driver.username = 'neo4j'
    config.neo4j.driver.password = '<my password>'
```

My error message is:

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.5/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:96:in `method_missing': undefined method `neo4j' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000271c086cf98
```

coming from my `config/application.rb`, specifically on this line:

```
config.neo4j.driver.url = ENV['NEO4J_URL'] || 'neo4j://localhost:7687'
```

I attempted to use the 'neo4j' gem and to add a require 'activegraph/railtie' in my application.rb but that did not solve the problem.  I also added my neo4j information in a config/neo4j.yml file, and that did not work either.

When I set up my project, I made it in API only mode and skipped ActiveRecord setup